# Chrome (Sheets specifically) is suddenly not printing embedded images correctly

Tags: google-chrome, google-sheets, printing

I have a spreadsheet in Google Sheets that I run in the Chrome browser (Mac OS). It loads images dynamically using the IMAGE function. Most of these images are large-scale icons that are then scaled down to fit into cells. For months I would print out pages generated this way and the icons would be scaled down very well, with clean edges etc.

All of a sudden three days ago, every time I print the icon images are pixelated and look terrible. This is also true for images that I embed directly into the sheet rather than using a dynamic function. I can't figure out what has changed.

Questions:

1- What does Chrome use to render images like large-scale icons that are scaled down to fit into cells? How does it manage this rendering when it comes to printing pages?

2- Was there some kind of recent update that changed the way these things should work? I've tried all kinds of adjustments but can't get it to print like it did consistently just a few days ago.

Many thanks

Comment: What makes you think this is a Chrome issue? Have you tried other browsers? You can view Chrome update history [here](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/). If you think this is Chrome related, you should file an issue report as detailled [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: As I said, it had been printing perfectly without any change for months before it suddenly stopped. The problem is either in Sheets specifically and related to how Sheets is embedding images (some kind of hidden update), or else more broadly with Chrome and how it's rendering, or rasterizing, images when they are sent to be printed. The most important clue here is, as I said, that things were working perfectly for months until they suddenly stopped, and this behavior is actually true across multiple spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: Interestingly, it turns out the issue was Google logging me out of the account that owned the spreadsheet (or perhaps having switched accounts to a different one). Somehow, once logged back in as the spreadsheet owner, all images printed normally again. Very strange but useful to know.